# Create a variable and pass as a parameter to the Rest API in Katalon Studio

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I have one requirement...I have to Create one Variable through the script and then I can able to use that variable as a parameter in Object Repository for API testing.

How can i do?

Can anybody please provide some suggestions and steps

Comment: What have you tried before?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create one Global variable with some value.
2) use the below step to update new value through the script to Global Variable.

GlobalVariable.variable_name= new value